# Null Pointer exception in java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, myfaces

I am getting the below exception when we access JSF pages concurrently by more than 10 users on a Tomcat. I am using JSF 2.0 (My faces 2.0.5 ) and rich faces 4. Please note it happens randomly and there are no steps to recreate this error. I started noticing it when we ran load test of 10 concurrent users on my application.

```
Please help !!!!. 

The exception is as follows

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet faces threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$EventListenerWrapper.isListenerForSource(UIComponent.java:1111)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2092)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:522)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._publishPostBuildComponentTreeOnRestoreViewEvent(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:436)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._publishPostBuildComponentTreeOnRestoreViewEvent(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:454)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._publishPostBuildComponentTreeOnRestoreViewEvent(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:466)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:349)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:66)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor361.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
```

Unfortunately we may not be able to upgrade myfaces due to time contraints.Basically I have few links on a dashboard page and its split in two sections. The first section displays all the links and second section which is underneath the first section displays the content of the link user clicks in first section. During our normal testing everything works fine and only during load testing we are seeing the exception provided in my post above whenever the user clicks on of the links (staff) in the dashboard page. Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks for all the your help.

Comment: Can you add more context to the question?

Comment: MyFaces 2.0.5 is ancient. Have you tried a more recent version?

Comment: I have updated my post with more details. Let me know if you have any questions. Appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by removing a JSTL tag  from the dashboard page. It was a basically a unused tag. This document helped me to resolve this issue.

http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/xref/org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.html

Thanks everyone for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same stacktrace.
My fault was, that I have used `<c:if />` with a condition, changend by an ajax request. This results in a component-tree modification during the request and seems to be problematic in some states.
My solution for the problem was to use an `<ui:fragment />` instead and bind the rendered-attribute to the condition. Maybe this helps anybody out there.

Comment: I have no new question. I just wanted to let other users know how I have solved the problem. I have modified my answer and I hope it is more clear now...